# What am I missing between version 6 & 7 of Android?

Tags: android

I have an admin app that developed about a year ago. There are 2 admins only (me and one other person). There is a login screen that requires user name/password.

Up until I upgraded my Note 5 from 6 to 7 - I was able to login without any issues. Now that I am on 7 that is no longer the case.

The other admin (who is using version 5 of Android) is having no issues. I have also successfully logged into the app on a Android emulator on my computer.

I have been unable to locate anything when reading about android 7 that would indicate there should be a problem with that part of the app as far as programming would go.

What am I missing?

Comment: You've given us no code, no error messages, and only the vaguest description of what's going on.  In current form this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Frankly since the code works in everything BUT Android 7 there was no need to post it - as far as error messages - the only produced error is the one I built into the system to notify user of wrong credentials when trying to sign in so that would be of no help - as far as your comment the question is unanswerable - someone else did even though it does not solve the issue (I had already done that) so your statement should have read it was unanswerable by you.

Comment: SO you got no help, no upvotes, and one answer that is both grammatically incomplete and makes sense only if you guess what he meant to say.  The reason-  you didn't give us any data to actually work with.  If you want an actual helpful answer, you need to provide sufficient data to solve the problem.  As it is, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I understood the other answer - it just did not solve the issue - as far as the code - as i said before - it works as it should except in Android 7 - but basically what it amounts to - if nobody is logged into the app on the device they are running - the app (via php) loads an array of all users that has their user name/encrypted pw - once a UN/PW are entered - it finds the array key of the matching user name (if it is a valid user) and checks the same array key for a valid PW - if valid you get logged in - if not - you see error message for bad credentials - pretty basic using .get()

Answer (score 0):

your

```
android:targetSdkVersion
```

make everything work

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution to this several weeks back but forgot to post it here. It turned out it had nothing to do with anything in the app. Within the php file that is called within the app (for importing data to the app) the "mobile device detection" that I was using did not detect my Note 5 (after upgrading to Ver 7) as a mobile device. I have since switched the detection method in the php file and everything started working properly again.